# >> shift operator not working as expected

Tags: c, gdb

I'm learning about the C language. I have this code, more can be provided if needed:

```
int result = 0;
int mask1 = 0x0000ffff;
mask1 = mask1 >> 28;
```

This when I use gdb and print `/x mask1`, I get `0x0`, which is correct.
Then why does:

```
int result = 0;
int mask1 = 0xffffffff;
mask1 = mask1 >> 28;

print 0xffffffff
```

shouldn't it be printing `0x0000000f`, since I'm left shifting 28 bits?

Does it have to do with the number of bits int takes up on my 64bit machine?
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812406/16-bit-int-vs-32-bit-int-vs-64-bit-int) but it didn't quite answer everything.

Comment: Make `mask1` an `unsigned int` and you will experience the behavior you expect (i.e. logical right shift).

Comment: Read pragmatic programmer, the book has a section titled "Select is not broken". It describes the problem you've run into here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bitwise right-shift of a negative integer is implementation-defined.

Here is what `gcc` does:

> *The results of some bitwise operations on signed integers (C90 6.3, C99 6.5).*
>
> Signed `>>' acts on negative numbers by sign extension.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of right shifts on negative integers is implementation defined. One common behaviour is arithmetic shifting, which does sign-extension. The advantage of that is that right shifting is then also division by a power of two (rounded to negative infinity), like it is for positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You're shifting *right*. This is right: `>>`, and this is left: `<<`.

Commonly, when you shift a (signed) integer right, you're assumed to be changing the *value* but not the *sign*: this is what Daniel means by *sign extension*. It isn't required by the standard and not all platforms do this.

In practise, on a system using twos complement, it means that negative values will have the new top bits filled with `1`, and positive values with `0`.

Eg, on an 8-bit 2s complement system:

```
before          after >> 1
11111110 = -2   11111111 = -1 (so new top bit was 1)
00000010 = +2   00000001 = +1 (so new top bit was 0)
```

Comment: The result of right-shifting a negative integer is implementation-defined.  It is not guaranteed to remain negative.

Answer (score 0):

if you print 0xffffffff as an integer, you will realize it is considered as -1.

Bitshift works differently with negative numbers, in that it fills the top most bit with a 1. So basically, 0xffffffff >> 1 == 0xffffffff.

If you declare the mask as `unsigned int`, then it will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @veer pointed out, with `int` you're doing a Right arithmetic shift which is great for dividing signed numbers by powers of 2 (in two's complement representation):

[image: Right arithmetic shift]

By changing the type to `unsigned int` it will become a Right bitwise shift which is great for dividing unsigned numbers by powers of 2 (which is your scenario):

[image: Right logical shift]

Some excellent explanation is on [Wikipedia Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).