# Loop over 256 values using 8-bit unsigned integer variable as counter

Tags: c, loops

So I was just trying to fill a buffer with consecutive numbers 0-255. I didn't think much on it and ended up in an infinite loop.

```
uint8_t i;
uint8_t txbuf[256];

for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
    txbuf[i] = i;
}
```

the problem being that `i` will never be 256 as it rolls over to zero after 255.

my question is, is there a way to do this loop without bumping `i` up to a 16 bit value?

Note: I know I could change the loop to `i<255` and add another line for the final spot but I'm trying to figure out of there is a nicer looking way.

Comment: Don't use an 8-bit `i`. Since a `uint8_t` can only have the values 0...255, `i < 256` will always be true. Use a regular `int` for the loop counter and just drop the extra bits on assignment.

Comment: the accepted answer works with an 8-bit value.

Comment: If you want to be able to end the loop after 0 iterations, you can't end it after 256, and vice versa. 0 to 256 = 257.

Comment: True, but a bad habit, I think. Loop indices should generally always be plain `int` unless there's some compelling reason they can't. On an ARM, for example, the accepted code would have to do a lot of extra masking since it can only do 32-bit fetches and stores.

Comment: `int` must have at least 16 bits, so there's no reason to use `uint8_t` in this case. In most cases using native width variables will generally be faster than 8-bit ones (except in arrays) https://stackoverflow.com/q/163254/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/5069489/995714 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/144792/98103 And even in the 8-bit world a smart compiler will optimize the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)` out without any use of 16-bit math, like how the 32-bit compiler [iterates over all unsigned integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40432995/995714)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
uint8_t txbuf[256];
uint8_t i = 0;

do {
   txbuf[i] = i;  
} while (i++ != 255);
```

or

```
uint8_t txbuf[256];
uint8_t i = 255; 

do {
   txbuf[i] = i;  
} while (i--);
```

Comment: Very nice! Since unsigned variables cannot overflow according to section 6.2.5.9 of C99 standard, the behavior is well defined.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `do ... while` loop so that you perform the action before checking the condition:

```
uint8_t i = 0;
uint8_t txbuf[256];

do {
    txtbuf[i] = i;
} while(i++ < 255);
```

Comment: I think it would be good to note that at the end of this loop `i==0` however that would only really matter if there is a `break` in the loop and you wanted to keep track of the index at the break point.

Answer (score 3):

The do..while loops in the other answers are probably what you want, but if you specifically want to use a for loop you can add a break statement:

```
uint8_t i;
uint8_t txbuf[256];

int main(void)
{

    for (i=0; ; i++) {
        txbuf[i] = i;
        if (i == 255) break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`uint8_t` ranges from 0-255 so it never becomes 256.
Since we see that your array is also of type uint8_t the value it can store is also from 0-255 so what makes you loop for values greater than 255?

Just keep your check as `i<255` and when you exit the loop you know the value of i is 255,use it accordingly.

Else use `do while` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

The following gcc (5.0) has a feature to check if an overflow occured.

```
uint8_t i = 0;
uint8_t txbuf[256];

do
{
    txbuf[i] = i;
}while(!__builtin_add_overflow(i,1,i));
```

More details at https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
uint8_t txbuf[256];
uint8_t i = 0;

do {
    txtbuf[i] = i;
} while(++i != 0);
```

The code allows for a change in type.