# Why is the same function with a different integer parameter size faster?

Tags: performance, rust

Motivated by the book *From Mathematics to Generic Programming*, I am playing around with functions and different integer sizes.

I have two different prime sieve implementations that work either with `u16` or `u32`. I benchmark them with `cargo bench` and the `u16` method is always a little faster than the `u32` method.

Why is this the case? My assumption is that my processor (i5-7300u) is able to do two adds at once for `u16` but not for `u32` or `u64`. Yet, I have no idea how to validate this. I've attached the assembly.

**Benchmark results**

> test tests::bench_sift2     ... bench:      74,093 ns/iter (+/- 3,765)
>
> test tests::bench_sift2_u16 ... bench:      61,136 ns/iter (+/- 3,389)

**EDIT**

Playing around with different array sizes and with the idea of using boolean arrays instead of vectors results in approx. the same speed for both functions. Actually the performance difference is only significant when the size of both vectors is 1<<15.

**EDIT 2**

Some interesting observation: I running this code on an windows surface computer with windows 10 Pro 10.0.1. More or less by accident, I just run the benchmark with different power saving configurations. When I set the configuration to highest performance, I see more or less the results reported below. If I set the configuration to any other level, I see results where both functions seem to behave the same, but the measurement error increases drastically.

**Rust Code**

```
#![feature(iterator_step_by)]
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

fn main() {
   let vec = sift2(1 << 15);
   // let vec = sift2_u16(1 << 15);
   println!("{}",vec[0]);
}


fn sift2(n: usize) -> Vec<bool> {
    let mut vec = vec![true; n];

    let mut i = 0;
    let mut index_square = 3;
    let mut factor = 3;

    while index_square < n {
        if vec[i] {
            mark_sieve(&mut vec[index_square..], factor);
        }
        i += 1;

        index_square += factor;
        factor += 2;
        index_square += factor;
    }

    vec
}

fn sift2_u16(n: u16) -> Vec<bool> {
    let mut vec = vec![true; n as usize];

    let mut i: u16 = 0;
    let mut index_square: u16 = 3;
    let mut factor: u16 = 3;

    while index_square < n {
        if vec[i as usize] {
            mark_sieve(&mut vec[index_square as usize..], factor as usize);
        }
        i += 1;

        index_square += factor;
        factor += 2;
        index_square += factor;
    }

    vec
}

fn mark_sieve(data: &mut [bool], factor: usize) {
    data.iter_mut().step_by(factor).for_each(|k| *k = false);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use super::*;
    use test::{black_box, Bencher};

    #[bench]
    fn bench_sift2(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| sift2(1 << 15));
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_sift2_u16(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| sift2_u16(1 << 15));
    }
}
```

**generated assembly for sift2**

```
    .text
    .def     _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    .globl  _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E:
.seh_proc _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    %r8, %r9
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    movq    %rcx, 32(%rsp)
    leaq    vtable.4(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r8
    callq   _ZN3std2rt19lang_start_internal17h273003faf754a099E
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E:
.seh_proc _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   *(%rcx)
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    jmp _ZN58_$LT$$LP$$RP$$u20$as$u20$std..termination..Termination$GT$6report17h23aa27a926e2484dE
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE:
.seh_proc _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   *%rcx
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    jmp _ZN58_$LT$$LP$$RP$$u20$as$u20$std..termination..Termination$GT$6report17h23aa27a926e2484dE
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E:
    movq    8(%rcx), %rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB3_1
    movq    (%rcx), %rcx
    movl    $1, %r8d
    jmp __rust_dealloc
.LBB3_1:
    retq

    .def     _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE:
    retq

    .def     _ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE:
.seh_proc _ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   __rust_oom
    ud2
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  __xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000
    .section    .rdata,"dr",discard,__xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000
    .p2align    4
__xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000:
    .quad   32768
    .quad   32768
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
.Lfunc_begin0:
.seh_proc _ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_handler __CxxFrameHandler3, @unwind, @except
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    pushq   %r14
    .seh_pushreg 14
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg 6
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg 7
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg 3
    subq    $128, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 128
    leaq    128(%rsp), %rbp
    .seh_setframe 5, 128
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    $-2, -8(%rbp)
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %r8
    movl    $32768, %ecx
    movl    $1, %edx
    callq   __rust_alloc
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    je  .LBB6_21
    movl    $32768, %r14d
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $32768, %r8d
    movq    %rdi, %rcx
    callq   memset
    movq    %rdi, -56(%rbp)
    movaps  __xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000(%rip), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, -48(%rbp)
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    movl    $3, %eax
    movl    $3, %ecx
    cmpb    $0, (%rdi,%rdx)
    jne .LBB6_3
    jmp .LBB6_10
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB6_12:
    addq    $2, %rax
    movq    -56(%rbp), %rdi
    cmpb    $0, (%rdi,%rdx)
    je  .LBB6_10
.LBB6_3:
    cmpq    %rcx, %r14
    jb  .LBB6_4
    cmpq    %rcx, %r14
    je  .LBB6_10
    addq    %rdi, %r14
    leaq    (%rdi,%rcx), %rdi
    leaq    -1(%rax), %rsi
    addq    $1, %rdi
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB6_9:
    movb    $0, -1(%rdi)
    movq    %r14, %rbx
    subq    %rdi, %rbx
    addq    %rax, %rdi
    cmpq    %rsi, %rbx
    ja  .LBB6_9
.LBB6_10:
    addq    %rax, %rcx
    addq    %rax, %rcx
    addq    $2, %rcx
    cmpq    $32767, %rcx
    ja  .LBB6_14
    addq    $1, %rdx
    movq    -40(%rbp), %r14
    cmpq    %rdx, %r14
    ja  .LBB6_12
.Ltmp6:
    leaq    panic_bounds_check_loc.j(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %r14, %r8
    callq   _ZN4core9panicking18panic_bounds_check17h677ced4df3a8276eE
.Ltmp7:
    jmp .LBB6_6
.LBB6_14:
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    movups  -56(%rbp), %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -64(%rbp)
    je  .LBB6_15
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    %rsi, -96(%rbp)
    leaq    _ZN43_$LT$bool$u20$as$u20$core..fmt..Display$GT$3fmt17h27a33a0bff6802a9E(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    leaq    ref.m(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -56(%rbp)
    movq    $2, -48(%rbp)
    leaq    ref.n(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $1, -32(%rbp)
    leaq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    $1, -16(%rbp)
.Ltmp2:
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN3std2io5stdio6_print17h38a18b84d105804dE
.Ltmp3:
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB6_19
    movl    $1, %r8d
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    callq   __rust_dealloc
.LBB6_19:
    nop
    addq    $128, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.LBB6_4:
.Ltmp0:
    movq    %r14, %rdx
    callq   _ZN4core5slice22slice_index_order_fail17hbd1edce8e1fe586aE
.Ltmp1:
.LBB6_6:
    ud2
.LBB6_21:
    movups  -48(%rbp), %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
    movaps  -80(%rbp), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, -48(%rbp)
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    ud2
.LBB6_15:
.Ltmp4:
    leaq    panic_bounds_check_loc.j(%rip), %rcx
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %r8d, %r8d
    callq   _ZN4core9panicking18panic_bounds_check17h677ced4df3a8276eE
.Ltmp5:
    jmp .LBB6_6
    .seh_handlerdata
    .long   ($cppxdata$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E)@IMGREL
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_endproc
    .def     "?dtor$13@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA";
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?dtor$13@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA":
.seh_proc "?dtor$13@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"
.LBB6_13:
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rsp)
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    pushq   %r14
    .seh_pushreg 14
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg 6
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg 7
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg 3
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    leaq    128(%rdx), %rbp
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_endproc
    .def     "?dtor$20@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA";
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?dtor$20@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA":
.seh_proc "?dtor$20@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"
.LBB6_20:
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rsp)
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    pushq   %r14
    .seh_pushreg 14
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg 6
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg 7
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg 3
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    leaq    128(%rdx), %rbp
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    -80(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .xdata,"dr",associative,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .p2align    2
$cppxdata$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
    .long   429065506
    .long   2
    .long   ($stateUnwindMap$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E)@IMGREL
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   6
    .long   ($ip2state$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E)@IMGREL
    .long   120
    .long   0
    .long   1
$stateUnwindMap$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
    .long   -1
    .long   "?dtor$13@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"@IMGREL
    .long   -1
    .long   "?dtor$20@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"@IMGREL
$ip2state$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
    .long   .Lfunc_begin0@IMGREL
    .long   -1
    .long   .Ltmp6@IMGREL+1
    .long   0
    .long   .Ltmp2@IMGREL+1
    .long   1
    .long   .Ltmp0@IMGREL+1
    .long   0
    .long   .Ltmp4@IMGREL+1
    .long   1
    .long   .Ltmp5@IMGREL+1
    .long   -1
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E

    .def     main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,main
    .globl  main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
main:
.seh_proc main
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    movslq  %ecx, %r8
    leaq    _ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 32(%rsp)
    leaq    vtable.4(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r9
    callq   _ZN3std2rt19lang_start_internal17h273003faf754a099E
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,main
    .seh_endproc

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,vtable.4
    .p2align    3
vtable.4:
    .quad   _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE
    .quad   8
    .quad   8
    .quad   _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .quad   _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .quad   _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.i
    .p2align    4
str.i:
    .ascii  "C:\\projects\\rust\\src\\liballoc\\vec.rs"

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,panic_bounds_check_loc.j
    .p2align    3
panic_bounds_check_loc.j:
    .quad   str.i
    .quad   36
    .long   1551
    .long   10

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.k
str.k:

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.l
str.l:
    .byte   10

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,ref.m
    .p2align    3
ref.m:
    .quad   str.k
    .quad   0
    .quad   str.l
    .quad   1

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,ref.n
    .p2align    3
ref.n:
    .quad   1
    .quad   0
    .quad   3
    .zero   8
    .quad   3
    .zero   8
    .long   32
    .long   0
    .byte   3
    .zero   7
```

**generated assembly for sift2_u16**

```
U16
    .text
    .def     _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    .globl  _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E:
.seh_proc _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    %r8, %r9
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    movq    %rcx, 32(%rsp)
    leaq    vtable.4(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r8
    callq   _ZN3std2rt19lang_start_internal17h273003faf754a099E
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h0092a1d276f89f87E
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E:
.seh_proc _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   *(%rcx)
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    jmp _ZN58_$LT$$LP$$RP$$u20$as$u20$std..termination..Termination$GT$6report17h23aa27a926e2484dE
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE:
.seh_proc _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   *%rcx
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    jmp _ZN58_$LT$$LP$$RP$$u20$as$u20$std..termination..Termination$GT$6report17h23aa27a926e2484dE
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E:
    movq    8(%rcx), %rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB3_1
    movq    (%rcx), %rcx
    movl    $1, %r8d
    jmp __rust_dealloc
.LBB3_1:
    retq

    .def     _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE:
    retq

    .def     _ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE:
.seh_proc _ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   __rust_oom
    ud2
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    .seh_endproc

    .def     _ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E;
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  __xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000
    .section    .rdata,"dr",discard,__xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000
    .p2align    4
__xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000:
    .quad   32768
    .quad   32768
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
.Lfunc_begin0:
.seh_proc _ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_handler __CxxFrameHandler3, @unwind, @except
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    pushq   %r14
    .seh_pushreg 14
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg 6
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg 7
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg 3
    subq    $128, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 128
    leaq    128(%rsp), %rbp
    .seh_setframe 5, 128
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    $-2, -8(%rbp)
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %r8
    movl    $32768, %ecx
    movl    $1, %edx
    callq   __rust_alloc
    movq    %rax, %r14
    testq   %r14, %r14
    je  .LBB6_23
    movl    $32768, %edi
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $32768, %r8d
    movq    %r14, %rcx
    callq   memset
    movq    %r14, -56(%rbp)
    movaps  __xmm@00000000000080000000000000008000(%rip), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, -48(%rbp)
    movw    $3, %r8w
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    movw    $3, %r9w
    cmpb    $0, (%r14,%rdx)
    jne .LBB6_3
    jmp .LBB6_12
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB6_14:
    movq    -56(%rbp), %r14
    cmpb    $0, (%r14,%rdx)
    je  .LBB6_12
.LBB6_3:
    movzwl  %r9w, %ecx
    cmpq    %rcx, %rdi
    jb  .LBB6_4
    testw   %r8w, %r8w
    je  .LBB6_8
    cmpq    %rcx, %rdi
    je  .LBB6_12
    addq    %r14, %rcx
    movzwl  %r8w, %ebx
    addq    %r14, %rdi
    leaq    -1(%rbx), %rax
    addq    $1, %rcx
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB6_11:
    movb    $0, -1(%rcx)
    movq    %rdi, %rsi
    subq    %rcx, %rsi
    addq    %rbx, %rcx
    cmpq    %rax, %rsi
    ja  .LBB6_11
.LBB6_12:
    addl    %r8d, %r9d
    addl    $2, %r8d
    addw    %r8w, %r9w
    js  .LBB6_16
    addq    $1, %rdx
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rdi
    cmpq    %rdx, %rdi
    ja  .LBB6_14
.Ltmp8:
    leaq    panic_bounds_check_loc.j(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rdi, %r8
    callq   _ZN4core9panicking18panic_bounds_check17h677ced4df3a8276eE
.Ltmp9:
    jmp .LBB6_6
.LBB6_16:
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    movups  -56(%rbp), %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -64(%rbp)
    je  .LBB6_17
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    %rsi, -96(%rbp)
    leaq    _ZN43_$LT$bool$u20$as$u20$core..fmt..Display$GT$3fmt17h27a33a0bff6802a9E(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    leaq    ref.m(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -56(%rbp)
    movq    $2, -48(%rbp)
    leaq    ref.n(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $1, -32(%rbp)
    leaq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    $1, -16(%rbp)
.Ltmp4:
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN3std2io5stdio6_print17h38a18b84d105804dE
.Ltmp5:
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB6_21
    movl    $1, %r8d
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    callq   __rust_dealloc
.LBB6_21:
    nop
    addq    $128, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.LBB6_4:
.Ltmp2:
    movq    %rdi, %rdx
    callq   _ZN4core5slice22slice_index_order_fail17hbd1edce8e1fe586aE
.Ltmp3:
    jmp .LBB6_6
.LBB6_8:
.Ltmp0:
    leaq    ref.b(%rip), %rcx
    callq   _ZN4core9panicking5panic17h42feaa2e0dc2c607E
.Ltmp1:
.LBB6_6:
    ud2
.LBB6_23:
    movups  -48(%rbp), %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
    movaps  -80(%rbp), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, -48(%rbp)
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN61_$LT$alloc..heap..Heap$u20$as$u20$alloc..allocator..Alloc$GT$3oom17h59b46cc14d642c9aE
    ud2
.LBB6_17:
.Ltmp6:
    leaq    panic_bounds_check_loc.j(%rip), %rcx
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %r8d, %r8d
    callq   _ZN4core9panicking18panic_bounds_check17h677ced4df3a8276eE
.Ltmp7:
    jmp .LBB6_6
    .seh_handlerdata
    .long   ($cppxdata$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E)@IMGREL
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_endproc
    .def     "?dtor$15@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA";
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?dtor$15@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA":
.seh_proc "?dtor$15@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"
.LBB6_15:
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rsp)
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    pushq   %r14
    .seh_pushreg 14
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg 6
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg 7
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg 3
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    leaq    128(%rdx), %rbp
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_endproc
    .def     "?dtor$22@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA";
    .scl    3;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?dtor$22@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA":
.seh_proc "?dtor$22@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"
.LBB6_22:
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rsp)
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    pushq   %r14
    .seh_pushreg 14
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg 6
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg 7
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg 3
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    leaq    128(%rdx), %rbp
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    -80(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17h98ac405189abf599E
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rdi
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .xdata,"dr",associative,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E
    .p2align    2
$cppxdata$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
    .long   429065506
    .long   2
    .long   ($stateUnwindMap$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E)@IMGREL
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   6
    .long   ($ip2state$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E)@IMGREL
    .long   120
    .long   0
    .long   1
$stateUnwindMap$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
    .long   -1
    .long   "?dtor$15@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"@IMGREL
    .long   -1
    .long   "?dtor$22@?0?_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E@4HA"@IMGREL
$ip2state$_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E:
    .long   .Lfunc_begin0@IMGREL
    .long   -1
    .long   .Ltmp8@IMGREL+1
    .long   0
    .long   .Ltmp4@IMGREL+1
    .long   1
    .long   .Ltmp2@IMGREL+1
    .long   0
    .long   .Ltmp6@IMGREL+1
    .long   1
    .long   .Ltmp7@IMGREL+1
    .long   -1
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,_ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E

    .def     main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,main
    .globl  main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
main:
.seh_proc main
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    movslq  %ecx, %r8
    leaq    _ZN8chapter34main17hfb06448c1bac2398E(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 32(%rsp)
    leaq    vtable.4(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r9
    callq   _ZN3std2rt19lang_start_internal17h273003faf754a099E
    nop
    addq    $40, %rsp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .section    .text,"xr",one_only,main
    .seh_endproc

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,vtable.4
    .p2align    3
vtable.4:
    .quad   _ZN4core3ptr13drop_in_place17hd909dec568d984beE
    .quad   8
    .quad   8
    .quad   _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .quad   _ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17hac4aa92a66ec8c82E
    .quad   _ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h9a20945579719b9dE

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.9
    .p2align    4
str.9:
    .ascii  "assertion failed: step != 0"

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.a
    .p2align    4
str.a:
    .ascii  "libcore\\iter\\iterator.rs"

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,ref.b
    .p2align    3
ref.b:
    .quad   str.9
    .quad   27
    .quad   str.a
    .quad   24
    .long   299
    .long   9

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.i
    .p2align    4
str.i:
    .ascii  "C:\\projects\\rust\\src\\liballoc\\vec.rs"

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,panic_bounds_check_loc.j
    .p2align    3
panic_bounds_check_loc.j:
    .quad   str.i
    .quad   36
    .long   1551
    .long   10

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.k
str.k:

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,str.l
str.l:
    .byte   10

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,ref.m
    .p2align    3
ref.m:
    .quad   str.k
    .quad   0
    .quad   str.l
    .quad   1

    .section    .rdata,"dr",one_only,ref.n
    .p2align    3
ref.n:
    .quad   1
    .quad   0
    .quad   3
    .zero   8
    .quad   3
    .zero   8
    .long   32
    .long   0
    .byte   3
    .zero   7
```

Comment: `my processor (i5-7300u) is able to do two adds at once for u16 but not for u32 or u64` no, it'll only do multiple operations at once with [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD), unless you manage to do pseudo SIMD within integer registers in some cases. And using a 16-bit type on modern 32 or 64-bit computers [would be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/163254/995714), so avoid it unless you have bandwidth limit (like in an array)

Comment: Okay, so my assumption seems to be wrong. Yet, if your claim holds then sift2 should be faster, shouldn't it? Also, the second answer (not the accepted one) in the referenced thread claims that 16 bit arithmetics should make no difference at all due to a compatibility layer. Thus, I am still confused why I see the the u16 being faster  ...

Comment: have you tried running it under perf? @LưuVĩnhPhúc *no, it'll only do multiple operations at once with SIMD* - that's a bit too broad of a statement. for simple instructions like mov, lea and add you can get > 1IPC on modern processors since the pipelines have multiple execution units for those that can process instructions in parallel.

Comment: My first thought would be to avoid the vector, and instead pass a mutable slice of bool of the right size. It'd great clarify the code if all the `Vec` related code disappeared. I'd also use `unsafe` gets to avoid panicking for the same reasons. I don't expect either to significantly change the measurements, just clean-up the assembly to make it more readable (and being able to better spot the differences).

Comment: When I rust the benchmarks on my computer (using an Intel Core i7-4770K on Linux), both versions are about the same speed (the difference is within the error margin).

Comment: Well, I just double checked if this was a just a outlier result (see edits), but the bench results still differ when using a vector size of 1<<15. For all other sizes the functions have approx same running time. I have no idea why and this behavior feels more and more esoteric.

Comment: I'd note that you're bench-marking with unstable features on an unstable release. This has the potential to introduce anomalies which cast into doubt any general conclusions about the performance of 16 vs 32 bit integer performance in Rust; you might just be benchmarking quirks in the unstable version and/or features. If you can rework it to run on a stable Rust using only stable features, that would be more telling.

Comment: @the8472 of course multiple instructions can be run at once under superscalar, but it's not like you just decrease the variable size and suddenly more variables can be calculated at once for the same operation (except for autovectorization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried Rust, but I know some good tools to do such performance analysis. So while it may not fully answer your question, you'll get tools to dig more into this.

When trying to understand low-level performance, you must look on the generated assembly, which you seems to have done by the output you provided. However, this is pretty unreadable like this. That's where my predilection tool comes in the game: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org). You can see [your code here](https://godbolt.org/g/sNg23G)

From the generated assembly, we see some differences. Let's just focus on 2 elements of the loops (you can check the others, but the idea & result is the same)

The test **while** in 32 bits:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 112]
cmp     qword ptr [rbp - 64], rax
jb      .LBB124_5
```

And the same in 16 bits:

```
mov     ax, word ptr [rbp - 98]
cmp     word ptr [rbp - 52], ax
jb      .LBB125_5
```

**mark_sieve** in 32:

```
.LBB124_8:
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 64]
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 48], rax
    mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 48]
    lea     rdi, [rbp - 96]
    call    <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as core::ops::index::IndexMut<core::ops::range::RangeFrom<usize>>>::index_mut
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 136], rdx
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 144], rax
    jmp     .LBB124_9
.LBB124_9:
    mov     rdx, qword ptr [rbp - 56]
    mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 144]
    mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 136]
    call    example::mark_sieve
    jmp     .LBB124_10
```

And in 16:

```
.LBB125_8:
    movzx   eax, word ptr [rbp - 52]
    mov     ecx, eax
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 48], rcx
    mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 48]
    lea     rdi, [rbp - 80]
    call    <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as core::ops::index::IndexMut<core::ops::range::RangeFrom<usize>>>::index_mut
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 120], rdx
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 128], rax
    jmp     .LBB125_9
.LBB125_9:
    movzx   eax, word ptr [rbp - 50]
    mov     edx, eax
    mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 128]
    mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 120]
    call    example::mark_sieve
    jmp     .LBB125_10
```

We can see some differences in this code:

- The u16 code can use 16bits (ax, cx, dc) or 32bits (eax, ecx, edx) registers, while the u32 code only uses 64bits (rax, rcd, rdx).
- u16 code uses **movzx** instead of **mov** for pointer deref.
- u16 reads 16bits or memory (word) while u32 reads 64bits (qword).

For these different instructions, you can see their relative execution time difference looking at the excellent [Agner Instruction Tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). (I would love to see them integrated in compiler explorer btw).
You CPU seems to be a KabyLake (so we'll use the Skylake architecture) so we'll take the tables starting page 231 (read this page for getting the abbreviations used in the tables).

From Agner tables, the number of uops between a **mov r64,m** and a **movzx r,m** are the same (1 uop), but the mov adds 2 cycles of latency.

The different accumulators also changes some optimizations done by the processor.

The compiler also performs other architecture dependent optimizations, like loop unrolling depending on the number of ALU available on the CPU. So depending on the compiler decisions, your code may behave differently between different CPUs.

The difference may also be due to code alignment, or cache optimization.

Regarding the power-management differences, this may by impacted by 2 elements : Frequency capping, and C-States management. The cstates are states where the cpu goes into different sleep states for short period of time. The impact of sleep/wakeup on the internals of a cpu are up to the firmware. So it's not something we can really check in detail (the analysis would also alter the results).

I made [a post about understanding Meltdown/Spectre attack](https://medium.com/@saruspete/meltdown-spectre-attacks-in-depth-b7bc94756afe), which explains the different optimizations a CPU can do under the hood (and that even assembly cannot reflect). You may also want to take a look at it to better understand why CPU optimization is hard, as we can't control a lot of parameters.

Happy hacking !