# Should I use a more universal variable alias/type or use the variable type's that the functions i will use take?

Tags: c, casting, typedef

## Introduction to the problem

So a few months back while i was really struggling to get better at C, i decided maybe its time for me to ditch the usual var types, char, short, int, long in favor of the alias provided in stdint.h those being the uint8_t, etc... The initial problem is that declaring long on some machine's has different byte size lengths than others but soon i started to see that it became a snob thing for me to "differentiate" me from other IT student's.

I'm now doing a project and as always, I started to use the variables aliases mentioned above, as they are easy for me to read, write and i don't have to wonder what storage allocation will my computer choose to use(i know the size doesn't change at will and its dependent on the computer running it, but not being evident and explicit causes me to just obsess over it).

As usual my debugger start's complaining from time to time especially due to pointer conversion's like so

```c
Passing 'int8_t *' (aka 'signed char *') to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is notclang(-Wpointer-sign)
```

## The Question

Although i usually just explicitly cast them i am just wondering if I'm making the code worse because of a preference of mine, and what is the good practice: using a more universal(to the project) variable alias, or just using the aliases depending on how will they be used(this implies using 2-3 different aliases on a file and probably 10+ project wide)?

## Example

```c
        png_voidp per_chunck_ptr; 
        size_t readnum; 
        FILE *fp;
        if ((fp = fopen(file, "rb")) == NULL){
            fp = NULL;
            //ERROR()
            //ABORT(GENERAL_OPENING_READ_FILE_ERROR, " ERR01 ");
        }
        int8_t *pop;
        pop=malloc(GENERAL_PNG_SIG_SIZE * sizeof(int8_t));
        readnum=fread(pop,sizeof(int8_t),GENERAL_PNG_SIG_SIZE,fp);
        if(readnum!=GENERAL_PNG_SIG_SIZE){
            fclose(fp);
            //ERR 5
            fp = NULL;
            fprintf(stderr, GENERAL_READ_FILE_ERROR, "ERR02");
            exit(5);
        }
        if(png_sig_cmp((png_const_bytep)pop, 0, GENERAL_PNG_SIG_SIZE)!= 0){
            fclose(fp);
            fp = NULL;
            fprintf(stderr, "File is not recognized as png file\n");
            //err 6
            exit(6);
        }
        free(pop);
```

*The error checking is terrible, i use like 6-7 different ways to print error's for no other reason than me learning new functions or just getting distracted and using a certain one once and forgetting it there but although the answer could extend to it lets only focus on the variable pop for now*

At the time i was pretty sure that the pointer "pop" would be used in the future as a parameter of a function which typically prefers png_bytep or in this case png_const_bytep and furthermore i the library has their own function for allocating memory although from what I've seen its not much different in its manner than using malloc, (although i haven't read the manual for the specific implementation and only know a few generic theoretical concepts about the designation(if you haven't figured it out, its PNG).

Now lets focus on size_t readnum, this part goes against what i said earlier since im using another alias when i could've just said uint64_t, the thing is that if im not wrong `size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).`(although there's types for bigger "words", like long double, which for what I've read is 10 bytes long, or __uint128_t which 16 bytes these aren't as easily used by the cpu and they require optimizations on software to be able to store and manipulate them, and again correct me here if im wrong) so i shouldn't use a uint8_t here because i know that if someday cpu manufacturers decide to increase the bit size, of the register storage, ALU, and memory adresses(i heard my professor even say that modern intel ones sometimes had around 80 bits) to something like 128 bits the size_t would move and my function could fail if it ever overflowed. This caused me to not use uint64_t

### Conclusion

So should i just quit using my preferences of exact variable size and instead use the variable aliases that the functions use, or is using exact size alias really better as they allow to define certain behavior more precisely

Comment: I think this might be relevant: [On 32-bit CPUs, is an 'integer' type more efficient than a 'short' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/163254)

Comment: In general, avoid needing casts.  Use the proper type.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i read various SO posts around that subject and although i can't disagree with doctor's and other well researched people,  on why we should always use the optimized 32 bit variable over other option's when dealing with regular number manipulation, i just get the idea that if everyone started coding with the least size possible even when not optimized for moving around iin the cpu, the space saved on cache could make it worth it as it would save a huge huge amount of time 
Although if i ever enter in a professional setting or with colleagues i tipically follow conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, use the exact width types when you need to control exactly how big a particular variable is, using any kind of bit manipulation, or when dealing with raw data.  You would use the base types when interacting with an API that specifies those types, i.e. if a function expects a `long`, pass it a `long` instead of a `uint64_t`.

Regarding the specific warning you're getting, that's because the type `char` may be either signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation.  So if you were to pass a `int8_t *` to a function expecting a `char *`, and that system happens define `char` as an unsigned type, then you have a mismatch.

This isn't a big deal however, since it's allowed to access an integer object via a pointer to either the signed or unsigned version of its type.

Comment: Though you should ask yourself why exactly you do not want to control how big a variable is. Using `stdint.h` is never wrong, using `int` and `char` etc is often wrong, especially when dealing with raw data and bit-wise operations.

Comment: The rule of thumb I follow is, if size is genuinely not a concern then use `int`. If size is important, and/or if using any kind of bit manipulation, use a specific type with a clearly defined number of bits.

Comment: @Lundin  Good point.  Added more detail.

Comment: oh yes i forgot that my project is very reliant on bit manipulation, flag's and precise byte size. Although i still use some libraries so...
A thing i forgot to address is that sometimes one library outputs a more loose variable size while the value needed for the other library is very strict(although i think there's flag's on the header's to prevent unexpected behavior on 32 bit old machines or even the library will outright refuse to work

Comment: Re “This isn't a big deal however, since it's allowed…”: Technically, `int8_t` may be a different type from `char` and from `signed char` even if it has the same size, width, and arithmetic properties. If so, then the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7 do not define aliasing arbitrary objects with `int8_t` the way they do with character types.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you trying to cast an `int8_t *` into a `char *`(aka `uint8_t *`)? The warning is for your code's safety. It's not because you're using aliases but because you're implicitly casting a signed integer type into an unsigned one.

In practice, you should use whatever your API expects. And, if you're not using any other library or stuff like that, use whatever suits you the best. If you want to be specific about the size, use the `stdint.h` values and if you want to be vague about the sizes(for eg. you want to second biggest type) use the normal C keywords. Beware that the "second biggest" type may be the same as the biggest or the third biggest.