# Should I use 'long' instead of 'int' on 64-bits in langs with fixed type size (like Java, C#)

Tags: c#, java, 32bit-64bit, d

In 10, or even 5 years there will be no [**Edit2:** server or desktop] 32-bit CPUs.

So, are there any advantages in using `int` (32bit) over `long` (64bit) ?
And are there any disadvantages in using `int` ?

---

**Edit:**

1. By `10 or 5 years` I meant on vast majority of places where those langs are used
2. I meant which type to use **by default**. This days I won't even bother to think if I should use `short` as cycle counter, just `for(int i...`. The same way `long` counters  already win
3. registers are already 64-bit, there is already no gain in 32 bit types. And I think some loss in 8 bit types (you have to operate on more bits then you're using)

Comment: Re: first sentence: `[citation needed]`.

Comment: @Matt: I meant `almost` and `on vast majority of places where those langs are used`. I thought it's not a big deal and kind of implied. And that would make question much longer without much benefit. Should I edit ? If 'yes', please propose how to word it - I'm not very good in english

Comment: See previous comment. But yes. Use the type that best describes the domain -- for instance, why would a `long` be used to store the "day of year"?

Comment: My roomba has a 16-bit processor.

Comment: @vcsjones: and... how many Java apps do you run on it ?

Comment: @Alexander - None - but it still has programming with all the same principals. Just because it doesn't run a modern language doesn't disqualify it.

Comment: about my 3rd point see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c/1148505#1148505)

Comment: For me the real questions is why is there no 128-bit primitive types. ;)

Comment: As always, you should use the type which is clearest to you. It is more important to be clear and simple than worry about what performance. 32-bit values still fit into cache better than 64-bit values and they can be faster on 64-bit JVMs.

Comment: @Peter: I was thinking if it's the time when using `int` becomes premature optimization (when I know for sure all my users are 64 bit). So that I can use `long` uniformly across the code

Comment: Unfortunately many functions builtin to Java only support `(int)` like sizes of arrays and collections. If you think you should be using `long` even just in case, I would use it. However, if you can't imagine a `long` would be useful, don't use it. If later you discover `long` is needed you can change the code. I think YAGNI still applies here. http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html

Comment: @Peter "...builtin to Java only support (int)" - it's good argument. Also thanks for link to YAGNI - interesting, though irrelevant here :) (it's more about not overengineer and not to waste time, IMO)

Comment: Changing `int` to `long` could be considered over-engineering and wasting time. ;)

Comment: @Peter: "...wasting time" Yeah, it's longer to type :)

Comment: 32-bit integers will be used as long as memory is at a premium. It's exactly the same reason floats are still used in performant applications (floating point registers are usually double size, or even greater). It's all about the memory, and memory is quickly becoming the bottleneck.

Comment: @Peter Alexander: aren't floating types different in this regard (I really don't know) ? I would think algorithms for operations like mul and div are significantly more complex for floats rather then for integers. W.r.t. memory, `short` and `byte` will occupy even less, but no one defaults to `short`. I'm wondering if it's because int was the largest atomic integer type for too long and now we should adopt current largest. (note, I'm not talking about performance-critical sections of code)

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov The time it takes you to write one more letter is worth so much more than the 4-bytes which are used.  On the other hand, if using a "long" instead of a "int" prevent just one bug, then using a long was definitively the best choice.

Comment: @Alexander: Well, yes, they are a bit more complex. What are you arguing? As for byte and short, people do use those in performant code. Also, it doesn't matter if it is performance critical. Operations on double take just as long as those on float. Likewise for integers. The difference is memory consumption, and you consume memory whether you are used in a hot piece of code or not.

Comment: @Peter Alexander, Main memory isn't as much of a premium as it used to be. I just bought a PC with 24 GB, however cache sizes are MUCH smaller (esp L1) and they are a premium.  I would say its the cache which makes using float more attractive.

Comment: @Peter Alexander "What are you arguing?": I thought `float` operations are faster then `double`, and it's complexity is say O(significant_digits^3), where as for integers it's O(bits_number^1) (numbers are completely made up), hence doubling bits number isn't that significant for integral types. Though now I see, thanks.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: [640 KB of Memory Ought to be Enough for Anybody](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/24-gigabytes-of-memory-ought-to-be-enough-for-anybody.html) ? :)

Comment: When Bill made his famous quote, 1 MB cost $16M. I am old enough to remember when that was. ;)

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov, In Java, many `float` operations are not much faster than `double` operations. Its to impact on the cache and memory bandwidth which can make more difference.

Comment: Come to think of it, $16M was possibly more than Bill was worth at the time.

Comment: "I think there is a world market for maybe five computers."
    - Thomas Watson (1874-1956), Chairman of IBM, 1943

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: **First**, mr. Gates never said that ), follow the link above. **Second**, WHAT ?? Sixteen millions of dollars for one megabyte of RAM? I knew computers used to be much more expensive, but had no idea to what extent.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: As for memory bandwidth, typical width today is [more than 16GB/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates#Memory_Interconnect.2FRAM_buses). So, I don't know if it's relevant for most apps

Comment: Perhaps he never said it but it was implied in the design of MS-DOS, which he didn't originally design. It was bought the full rights for $50K http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/86-DOS In hindsight, a good investment. ;)

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov, I would agree that using `double` is better than `float` most of the time as it has reduced rounding error. But there are some applications where using `float` matters.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Main memory is at a premium on embedded devices, and remember that the *vast* majority (something like 99%+) of computers are embedded (think of all the electronic devices you own that have computers that need software). Also, as you say, cache memory is also at a premium, so in either case the point stands.

Comment: @Peter Alexander, We agree, perhaps for different reasons.  I would be surprised if such a high percentage of computers which do floating point are embedded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on a 64-bit processor, and you've compiled your code for 64-bit, then at least some of the time, `long` is likely to be more efficient because it matches the register size. But whether that will really impact your program much is debatable. Also, if you're using `long` all over the place, you're generally going to use more memory - both on the stack and on the heap - which could negatively impact performance. There are too many variables to know for sure how well your program will perform using `long` by default instead of `int`. There are reasons why it could be faster and reasons why it could be slower. It could be a total wash.

The typical thing to do is to just use `int` if you don't care about the size of the integer. If you need a 64-bit integer, then you use `long`. If you're trying to use less memory and `int` is far more than you need, then you use `byte` or `short`.

x86_64 CPUs are going to be designed to be efficient at processing 32-bit programs and so it's not like using `int` is going to seriously degrade performance. Some things *will* be faster due to better alignment when you use 64-bit integers on a 64-bit CPU, but other things will be slower due to the increased memory requirements. And there are probably a variety of other factors involved which could definitely affect performance in either direction.

If you really want to know which is going to do better for your particular application in your particular environment, you're going to need to profile it. This is not a case where there is a clear advantage of one over the other.

Personally, I would advise that you follow the typical route of using `int` when you don't care about the size of the integer and to use the other types when you do.

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/3mss9b/any_idea_why_this_go_loop_is_faster_than_pure_c/cvj478g

Answer (score 13):

32-bit is still a completely valid data type; just like we have 16-bit and bytes still around. We didn't throw out 16-bit or 8-bit numbers when we moved to 32-bit processors. A 32-bit number is half the size of a 64-bit integer in terms of storage. If I were modeling a database, and I knew the value couldn't go higher than what a 32-bit integer could store; I would use a 32-bit integer for storage purposes. I'd do the same thing with a 16-bit number as well. A 64-bit number takes more space in memory as well; albeit not anything significant given today's personal laptops can ship with 8 GB of memory.

There is no disadvantage of int other than it's a smaller data type. It's like asking, "Where should I store my sugar? In a sugar bowl, or a silo?" Well, that depends on entirely how much sugar you have.

Processor architecture shouldn't have much to do with what size data type you use. Use what fits. When we have 512-bit processors, we'll still have bytes.

**EDIT**:

To address some comments / edits..

1. I'm not sure about "There will be no 32-bit desktop CPUs". ARM is currently 32-bit; and has [declared little interest in 64-bit](http://www.techspot.com/news/42299-arm-ceo-were-not-going-64-bit-anytime-soon.html); for now. That doesn't fit too well with "Desktop" in your description; but I also think in 5-10 years the landscape of the type of devices we are writing software will drastically change as well. Tablets can't be ignored; people will want C# and Java apps to run on them, considering Microsoft officially ported Windows 8 to ARM.
2. If you want to start using `long`; go ahead. There is no reason not to. If we are only looking at the CPU (ignoring storage size), and making assumptions we are on an x86-64 architecture, then it doesn't make much difference.
3. Assuming that we are sticking with the x86 architecture; that's true as well. You may end up with a slightly larger stack; depending on whatever framework you are using.

Comment: +1 to this. I could definitely learn more about the subject (and I welcome any and all correcting comments, as they are pedagogic) but I think that the OP would probably be fine as long as the sizes are powers of two. In five or ten years, you'd probably be rewriting that application anyway (for completely separate reasons)... :P

Comment: **1.** I meant "by default". This days I won't even bother to think if I should use `short` as cycle counter, just `for(int i...`. The same way in counters `long` already wins (see next point) **2.** I'm not talking about DB storage - it's a bit different. While execution Java or C# vars (int or long) are stored on registers. And since registers are already 64-bit wide, I win nothing by using int or short

Comment: @Alexander, You're right in that most CPUs are 64 bit these days, but the point is that it's not yet ALL CPUs. If you use long variables on a 32 bit CPU then it will be slower because it has to handle numbers larger than a single register can handle. So if you don't need 64 bits worth of values then you don't gain much by using long, and if someone with a 32 bit machine wants to run your program then you could be disadvantaging them. (Whether they'd notice or not is another matter...)

Comment: @Chris: In my case I know for sure - I'm doing Java for my company's server :). Also see my reply to Peter Lawrey in comments to OP

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the C++ answer.

If the size of the type matters use a sized type:

- `uint8_t`
- `int32_t`
- `int64_t`
- etc

If the size doesn't matter use an expressive type:

- `size_t`
- `ptrdiff_t`
- `ssize_t`
- etc

I know that D has [sized types](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdint.html) and `size_t`.  I'm not sure about Java or C#.

Comment: Plus one for the D-Reference of the day

Comment: We got the integral type mess from C++ in C#, but not the typedef to deal with it.