# Using downcasting in real app life

Tags: java, downcast

I know that implicit casting is done automatically by the compiler and virtual machine, and that explicit casting is needed to convert types of data when Java is not sure if the result will be valid. Casting should be done between primitives or between objects.

My question is:  If my application uses both integers as well as long integers - should I use `long` for both types? Or downcasting for `long`? Or casting for `int`?

Can usage of long for both types causes some problems?

Comment: You should make sure that your variable can accommodate all valid values. If a variable can contain values larger than the largest integer, it should be a long.

Comment: @Heuster: So just take long for everything?

Comment: @Thilo I think you in practice hardly ever encounter a 'lonely' long... either many values are large (in which case long is the only logical choice), or none at all. So no, not just long for everything, only long when it makes sense :)

Comment: @Thilo `long` is common to represent currency (given precision issues with `float`), it's also common to represent a timestamp, and also for auto-incrementing IDs. Point being: there are specific use cases for which a 64 bit integer is necessary, and 9/10 of these are things that - given the proper forethought - you will be able to recognize during your design phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will probably go with the right datatype for right operations , `long` if I need `long` , `int` if `int` is enough for my requirements . **Common sense would be to think  using `long` for `int` probably will slow you down in general**, but again this depends on the specific JVM implementation. You will have to decide based on the range which you want to target .

Again , if there are lots of casting involved in your program , then better to go for a datatype like **`long` which can accommodate a larger range than `int` and save you from casts and loss of data in that process** . Having said that , `long` might be slower than `int`although in modern processors and JVMs I doubt that might affect much .

May be , enlightened ones here can answer this question better.

You can also read some nice SO Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903235/will-using-longs-instead-of-ints-benefit-in-64bit-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825023/should-i-use-long-instead-of-int-on-64-bits-in-langs-with-fixed-type-size-l).

Comment: It will also, of course, take more memory to use `long` everywhere

Comment: I don't think long is slower than int, although as you said this depends on the JVM implementation for the underlying architecture. Most likely 64-bit JVMs will have no speed issues when using long (and maybe even it's faster than using int since it's the native word length)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use a data type that covers all your values, so I would use `long` for everything, because it simplifies the code and avoids potentially risky conversions.

- Casting from `long` to `int` can make you lose data since a `long` is bigger than an `int` (thus data is truncated in the cast).
- Casting from `int` to `long` is **almost** (see Colin Morelli's comment about this below) the same as using `long` from the beginning and you avoid juggling with 2 types . Also this casting just doesn't make sense as you're taking up memory for nothing actually (unless you were using an `int` and a method explicitly requires a `long` as parameter, then you obviously have no choice but cast).

The downsides I see using `long` are:

- `long` doubles the memory needed instead of `int` (still take into account Colin Morelli's comment below).
- `long` *might* yield slower performance (as said above, but I'm not sure about this)

Comment: Casting from `int` to `long` is not the same as using `long` from the beginning, actually. Since primitives are passed by value, you could pass an `int` 5 levels deep and _then_ do a `long` conversion, leaving you with 5 `int`s and 1 `long`, versus having 6 `long`s. In that particular scenario, the difference is minimal, but it could result in a potentially large memory difference

Comment: @ColinMorelli absolutely, I didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on your date range. Take a look at [The Java Tutorials: Primitive Data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) if you know that your numbers will be between [Integer.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) don't sweet, casting will work as expected. Else, go for `long` or [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: What happens if only some data cannot fit into int? Say 1% is long, 99% is int.

Comment: This is a business decision. You either throw errors for the 1% or pay the overheads to accommodate the corner cases, it depends on how relevant the 1% really is.

Comment: Business decision? Since when does business understands what a long is?

Comment: They do understand how relevant those 1% of really big numbers really are.

Comment: Relevant? I don't understand what you mean. You have to process **all** (100%) the data, not discard that 1% (this is the OP question btw...).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more clear on the range of numbers you are dealing with. Well with the given input the best bet would be to go with `long`. But If you really need to make it generic and memory is not a constraint then you could use `BigInteger`.