# Should I use int or long in C++?

Tags: c++, int

While the size of `int` depends on the CPU, `long` seems to be 32 bit (?). But it seems so intuitive to use `int` for numbers where size doesn't really matter, like in a for loop.

It's also confusing that C++ has both `long` and `__int32`. What is the second for then?

**Question:** What number types should I use in what situations?

Comment: No, long is not always 32 bits...

Comment: long is not smaller than int. At least 32 bits.

Comment: I really like C# for the data-types. They are always the same, everywhere. In C++, I'm not even sure anymore if I should use `int` at all.

Comment: There are [fixed-size integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) in the standard library.

Comment: if C++ standard mandates the fixed size for types then creating a compiler 12, 18, 24, 36, etc-bit systems would be a pain. `__int32` and `__int64` is not a standard type

Comment: `int` should always the default type because all narrower types would be promoted to it or `unsigned int`, unless you need at least 64 bits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825023/should-i-use-long-instead-of-int-on-64-bits-in-langs-with-fixed-type-size-l On most systems operations on int will be at least equal or sometimes better than long. If long is 64 bits then on x86 they'll also need longer instructions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `int` and `long` don´t have fixed sizes (or any fixed representation at all), as long they can hold specific value ranges (including that `long` can´t be smaller than `int`).

For specific sizes, there are some types like `int32_t` etc. (which may be the same).

And `__int32` isn´t standard C++, but a compiler-specific thing (eg. MSVC)

Comment: Why did Microsoft add `__int32`, if it's the same as the standard `int32_t`?

Comment: I think that int32_t implemented ad typedef of __int32

Comment: What should I use if I want exactly 32 bit then?

Comment: I mean that __int32 is native type for msvc compiler, and standard types implemented through native types

Comment: @bytecode77 `Why did Microsoft add __int32` Who knows...but MSVC has so much non-standard things (while "forgetting" to implement some standard stuff for about 16 years...)

Comment: `What should I use if I want exactly 32 bit then?` `int32_t` (which may not exist on some strange hardware platforms)

Comment: you can find type int32_t in every compiler that implements c++ standard, so you can compile code using both msvc, gcc (mingw), it is cross-platform aproach

Comment: I belive `_int32` was added before `int32_t` was introduced.

Comment: When sticking to MSVC and all of its non-standard stuff, is `__int32` a "prettier" option? I assume so because it's highlighed as a keyword rather than a class.

Comment: @bytecode77 `int32_t` isn´t a class, it´s a "normal" int type too. And no. While MSVC has problems with fulfilling the requirements, it knows `int32_t`, and using compiler-specific things if you have independent alternatives will make your code harder to use on other systems, nothing more.

Comment: I believe `__int32` is used when exact width is needed, because this predates the fixed-width types in C99 and C++11 and in DOS and 16-bit windows, int has only 16 bits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc So you´re saying that we should use `__int32` if using such old MSVC versions that it doesn´t know anything of C99 yet. Well, yes, but I´m assuming new tools here.

Comment: yes, but MSVC compiler has been there a long time. Even before long long exists, so they created `__int64`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Well, yes...? I still don´t see a reason to use this types when writing new code in new VS versions.

Comment: did I say you must use it in new code? They're created for MS (historical) purposes

Answer (score 2):

Standard specifies, that `long` is not shorter than `int` - Specified in C++ standard §3.9.1

C++11 introduced integers with fixed number of bytes, like `int32_t`.

Comment: The header <stdint> was available a long time before c++11.

Answer (score -2):

Note that `int` is 32 bits even on many 64-bit architecture/compiler combinations (the 64-bit versions of gcc and MSVC both use 32 bits, as far as I know). On the other hand, `long` will typically be 64 bits on a 64-bit compiler (not on Windows, though).

These are only guidelines though, you always have to look into your compiler's manual to find out how these datatypes are defined.

Comment: Could somebody perhaps explain why this is downvoted?