# Any reason to prefer single precision to double precision data type?

Tags: c#, .net

I am used to choosing the smallest data type needed to fully represent my values while preserving semantics.  I don't use `long` when `int` is guaranteed to suffice. Same for `int` vs `short`.

But for real numbers, in C# there is the commonly used `double` -- and no corresponding `single` or `float`.  I can still use `System.Single`, but I wonder why C# didn't bother to make it into a language keyword like they did with `double`.

In contrast, there are language keywords `short`, `int`, `long`, `ushort`, `uint`, and `ulong`.

So, is this a signal to developers that single-precision is antiquated, deprecated, or should otherwise not be used in favor of `double` or `decimal`?

(Needless to say, single-precision has the downside of less precision.  That's a well-known tradeoff for smaller size, so let's not focus on that.)

**edit**: My apologies, I mistakenly thought that `float` isn't a keyword in C#. But it is, which renders this question moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a default, any literal like `2.0` is automatically interpreted as a `double` unless otherwise specified. This could contribute to the consistently higher use of `double` than other floating-point representations. Just a side note.

As far as the absence of *`single`* goes, the **`float`** keyword translates to the `System.Single` type.

Answer (score 8):

The [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) alias represents the .NET [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) data type so I would say it's safe to use.

Answer (score 5):

There is the following correspondence between C# keywords and .NET type names:

```
double -  System.Double
float  -  System.Single
```

So there's one keyword in C# for each of the two types in question.

I don't know how you got the impression that `float` was not a C# keyword. It certainly is.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a `float` keyword for single precision floating point.

Also, don't be so sure about `short` or `byte` being a better fit than `int`. `int` is usually the best choice for integer numbers. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2):

C# System.Single is aliased to 
[`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)