# Impossible value in lambda expression

Tags: c#, arrays, concurrency, lambda

can anyone please tell me, how is it possible that this code:

```
for (byte i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
{
    pool.QueueTask(() =>
        {
            if (i > 0 && i < someArray.Length)
            {
                myFunction(i, someArray[i], ID);
            }
        });
}
```

falls on the line where `myFunction` is called with `IndexOutOfRangeException` because the `i` variable gets value equal to `someArray.Length`? I really do not understand to that...

Note: `pool` is an instance of simple thread pool with 2 threads.

Note2: The type `byte` in for loop is intentionally placed because the array length can not go over byte max value (according to preceding logic that creates the array) and I need variable `i` to be of type `byte`.

Comment: Your array's not got more than 256 elements, has it?

Comment: @Flynn1179 it has 100 elements (that is why I use byte)

Comment: byte is slower than int. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1148505/4767498

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary well actualy, I use byte because of avoiding conversion from int to byte. The function takes first parameter byte and it serves as a data value for some data structure, which I store in binary file with custom layout - one byte, one long and so... So thank for effort, but that is not applicable for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is creating a closure on `i`, and it will end up being `someArray.Length` every time it's executed. The `Action` that you end up passing into `QueueTask()` retains the state of the for loop, and uses the value of `i` at execution time. Here is a compilable code sample that expresses this same problem,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var someArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    var fns = new List<Action>();

    for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
    {
        fns.Add(() => myFunction(i, someArray[i]));
    }

    foreach (var fn in fns) fn();
}

private static void myFunction(int i, int v)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{v} at idx:{i}");
}
```

You can break this by copying the closed around variable in a local, which retains the value of `i` at creation time of the `Action`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var someArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    var fns = new List<Action>();

    for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var local = i;
        fns.Add(() => myFunction(local, someArray[local]));
    }

    foreach (var fn in fns) fn();
}

private static void myFunction(int i, int v)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{v} at idx:{i}");
}
```

Related reading: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Comment: @Sehnsucht - Thank you!

Comment: There is actually a related breaking changing with C# 5.0 and the `foreach` loop, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx that may interest you to read about as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `byte` as index seems like a premature micro-optimization, and it will indeed cause trouble if your array has more than 255 elements.

Also, while we're at it: you mention that you're running on a threadpool. Are you making sure that the `someArray` does not go out of scope while the code is running?