# Why does Color use Int32 over Byte?

Tags: c#, .net, types

Using this example:

[Color.FromArgb(Int32, Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a Color structure from the specified 8-bit color values (red,
> green, and blue). The alpha value is implicitly 255 (fully opaque).
> Although this method allows a 32-bit value to be passed for each color
> component, the value of each component is limited to 8 bits.

If the value of each component is limited to 8 bits, then why didn't they use `Byte` instead of `Int32`?

In broader scope, I find people using `Int32` very commonly, even when `Int16` or `Byte` would suffice. Is there any particular reason for using `Int32` *generally* over `Int16`, `Byte`, etc?

Comment: 32-bit is more native to a typical machine, I guess? Not sure about that, this is a comment only... ;)

Comment: The "generally" question has a completely different answer. I advise editing that out.

Comment: Perhaps it saves you a downcast?

Comment: @TGlatzer It saves you having to write one yourself, but [internally it does one (or rather 4) anyway](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1555).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use int instead of a byte or short in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes - that was my Point - more from a too-lazy-too-type Point of view than a Performance Point of view :)

Comment: Lost in the fog of time.  I'd guess that the .NET programmer copied the previously existing C++ wrapper literally, it also uses *int*.  There are in general *very* few differences between gdiplus.h and System.Drawing.

Comment: @HansPassant do you know that you *could be right* about that? ;) See Anders Tornbald's answer

Comment: Maybe.  Probably.  It is just a guess that doesn't help anybody do anything differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that byte is less well supported by some .NET languages. Maybe it's not CLS compliant, I don't remember. These days nobody cares about CLS compliance anymore but in the 1.0 days this was an important feature level. Also note that VB.NET does not support unsigned types well which is an example of different support for integers across .NET languages.

Using `int` for the constructor is especially weird because the `A, R, G, B` properties are `byte`.

I consider this to be an API design error.

The `Color` struct is not particularly beautiful in general. It does not only have ARGB values but also a `KnownColor` and a name. Many concerns have been crammed into this struct. For fun, the `Equals` method has a [bug](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Color@cs/1/Color@cs): `return name.Equals(name);`. This is always true, of course. This struct looks hastily done. You can tell from the `Equals` method that the code author did not know that strings have an overloaded equality operator. The operator equals of `Color` is the same 15 lines just copied over. I guess the true answer for this question is: *The intern did it!*

---

*Generally*, `Int32` is preferred because most arithmetic operations widen to 32 bits and it's an efficient integer width for common hardware. The shorter integer types are for more special uses.

Since it was suggested that this saves downcasting: I do not understand that point. Widening integer conversions are implicit and have no meaningful performance cost (often none).

Comment: FWIW byte is compliant, sbyte is not.

Comment: @AlexK. alright, maybe the author of `Color` did not know that :) (Joking.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good reason. First, I thought that digging into the code would provide some insight, but all I can find is that there are checks to ensure that the values of `alpha`, `red`, `green` and `blue` are within the [0..255] range, throwing an exception if not. Internally, the `MakeArgb` method is then called, which **does** use `byte`:

```
/// <summary>
///     [...]
///     Although this method allows a 32-bit value
///     to be passed for each component, the value of each
///     component is limited to 8 bits.
/// </summary>
public static Color FromArgb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)
{
    Color.CheckByte(alpha, "alpha");
    Color.CheckByte(red, "red");
    Color.CheckByte(green, "green");
    Color.CheckByte(blue, "blue");
    return new Color(Color.MakeArgb((byte)alpha, (byte)red, (byte)green, (byte)blue), Color.StateARGBValueValid, null, (KnownColor)0);
}

private static long MakeArgb(byte alpha, byte red, byte green, byte blue)
{
    return (long)((ulong)((int)red << 16 | (int)green << 8 | (int)blue | (int)alpha << 24) & (ulong)-1);
}

private static void CheckByte(int value, string name)
{
    if (value < 0 || value > 255)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("InvalidEx2BoundArgument",
                                    name,
                                    value,
                                    0,
                                    255));
    }
}
```

I guess it just became that way in the early days *(we're talking .NET 1.0 here)* and then it just stuck.

Also, there **is** the `FromArgb(int)` overload, which lets you set all 32 bits with one 32 bit value. Strangely, this is an `int` and not a `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Color` struct itself uses the `byte` type for the R, G, B and A components.

I think that they've chosen to use `int` as the parameter types even when `byte` would suffice because it'll save the user from casting back to a type when converting an ARGB representation of the color to the `Color` struct, as the name says. Which would be done as:

```
int argb = 0xffff0000; // Red
Color red = Color.FromArgb((argb & 0xff000000) >> 24, (argb & 0x00ff0000) >> 16, (argb & 0x0000ff00) >> 8, argb & 0x000000ff);
```

Making the coder cast each character to a byte manually would lengthen that line by `"(byte)()".Length * 4` = 32 characters.

Plus, they can and *do* raise an `ArgumentException` when the values are greater than 255 or less than 0 to **properly** inform the user that they've entered the wrong input, instead of just clamping the values. Maybe they forgot to normalize the components after using a higher-precision `Color` representation?

Comment: `argb & 0xff000000` converted to byte is always zero, you're missing a shift. The "right" way to do this is `(byte)(argb >> 24)`. The cast to byte is included.

Comment: @usr Oops, my bad. Edited my answer.