# Can i use bytes instead of int or shorts to save processing?

Tags: c#, for-loop, .net-core

My program is getting complex, i want to save processing, so, i'm replacing ints for shorts, but, i'm a beginner, don't know if use bytes will make anything don't work correctly.
So, in a **for** with a short contage, it's good to use bytes? Like this:

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Have any problem to use bytes in a contage less than 256?

Comment: What is a contage? Anyway, this almost certainly seems like premature optimization and in the wrong place.

Comment: See [Why should I use int instead of a byte or short in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c-sharp)

Comment: use lower level language(C) if you really want to lower resource.

Comment: I guess with contage he means count?

Comment: "i'm a beginner" -> use the least fancy approach (int). Then when not beginner, allow yourself to get fancy.

Comment: using a byte in this case doesn't save you processing but memory.. but you are not saving that much memory just 3 bytes.. which is not worth the 'complexity' imo

Comment: In memory a byte is likely to consume 4 bytes as well due to alignment optimizations.