# how important is it to declare the correct variable type

Tags: c#, declaration

If I have a number only between 1 & 10 is it overkill declare it as `int` or should you use `short`, `Long`, `sbyte`?

`int x = 5;` or `sbyte x = 5;`

Comment: No overkill. Sometimes over optimization is worse.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129023/net-integer-vs-int16

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil - Donald Knuth

Comment: This is actually fairly subjective - since the importance can vary greatly depending on the application's purpose.

Comment: When I was a student, I tried to increase performance by using bytes + shorts (in C) whenever possible. A professor told me not to both as decent compilers will optimize a lot of that away anyway.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `Long` as it's even bigger than `int` :) As for the rest... Do you really care for that 3 wasted bytes? Premature optimization is evil.

Comment: Why not use four `bool` instances? =)

Comment: `enum` would be better then four `bool`, since you can't use subrange types IMHO :)

Answer (score 2):

`int` is handled faster on 32 bit processors, since its size is equal to CPU register size. If you don't have additional requirements (the need to conserve memory, for example), use `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context I would say just use an int.  Overkill only matters when you have space constraints or it overly complicates what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not really unless your are tying to get minuscule amounts of performance and memory footprint out of your application.

However I would suggest using the correct type if not for readability purposes and also so that if the value increases above it's allocated type size then this potential bug will be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Call a dog a dog and a salesman a salesman. Declaring your variables in the right type is fundamental for code readability and accuracy.

Now, for your example, if you are sure it's only from one to 10, you can use `sByte`. I would, however, use `int`. We should not overcomplicate, whenever we can.

Also, as well noticed by @ElRonnoco, if you are planning to execute calculations, you might get an overflow error when dealing with small numeric types so you should stick to `int` for most things.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with this. As others have stated `int` is accessed more efficiently. Also - perhaps at some point you may want to process these values (eg take an average). Summing them may lead to overflow issues, extra casting required etc etc...

Comment: You are right. I had updated my answer before your comment though :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity in your code is an important feature for long term maintainability.  Unless optimization is vitally important such as in super high speed applications (games where instant reactions are critical), don't waste time worrying over a few bytes that would make it harder for the next guy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, don't optimize. Over optimization in the early stages of a code base is usually a bad idea and leads to abstraction leakage, bad versatility of the code base and hard to debug problems. Stick with the most common types in the type system and whenever you discover that the type only needs to be `short` or `uint`, you can always change type later on.

It's easier to start out wide and narrow the types down than the other way around and before you have a working code base that integrates with 3rd party systems and such, it's impossible to know exactly where the boundaries in your code needs to be drawn.