# What is the difference between int, Int16, Int32 and Int64?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between `int`, `System.Int16`, `System.Int32` and `System.Int64` other than their sizes?

Answer (score 452, accepted):

Each type of integer has a different range of storage capacity

```
   Type      Capacity

   Int16 -- (-32,768 to +32,767)

   Int32 -- (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647)

   Int64 -- (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807)
```

As stated by James Sutherland in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care/62555#62555):

> `int` and `Int32` are indeed synonymous; `int` will be a little more
>   familiar looking, `Int32` makes the 32-bitness more explicit to those
>   reading your code. I would be inclined to use int where I just need
>   'an integer', `Int32` where the size is important (cryptographic code,
>   structures) so future maintainers will know it's safe to enlarge an
>   `int` if appropriate, but should take care changing `Int32` variables
>   in the same way.
>
> The resulting code will be identical: the difference is purely one of
>   readability or code appearance.

Comment: If you know the value isn't going to be exceed 65,535(signed) or −32,768 to 32,767(unsigned) wouldn't it be better to define the integer as `int16` to save memory resource, opposed to simply using `int`?

Comment: int and int32 can be synonymous, but they need not be. Nowadays, most systems sold are 64-bit in which case an int will be 64 bits.

Comment: For Matthew T. Baker and any others like myself who came here trying to decide which to use from a performance standpoint, you should check out this post that suggests Integer is more efficient than Int16 in many cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129023/net-integer-vs-int16

Comment: @MartijnOtto The question is tagged C#. In C#, `int` is *always* `Int32`, regardless of the system. Perhaps you're thinking of C++?

Comment: I had `int` variable declaration and got a run time exception `Value was either too large or too small for an Int16. at System.Int16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)` Replaced declaration with `Int32` and the problem was solved.

Comment: @MattBaker: In general, on modern computers, an int16 takes as much space as an int32 (and actually an int64) because in order for most operations to be efficient, we pad around the data to make accesses aligned to 32 or 64 bit boundaries (in 32 or 64 bit modes respectively). This is because unaligned accesses are ridiculously inefficient on some architectures, and not possible on others.

Comment: @Matt Baker you have signed and unsigned mixed up in your comment.

Comment: int is an alias for Int32, 
long is an alias for Int64

Answer (score 137):

The only real difference here is the size.  All of the int types here are signed integer values which have varying sizes

- `Int16`: 2 bytes
- `Int32` and `int`: 4 bytes
- `Int64` : 8 bytes

There is one small difference between `Int64` and the rest.  On a 32 bit platform assignments to an `Int64` storage location are not guaranteed to be atomic.  It is guaranteed for all of the other types.

Comment: If I use `Int64` in `32 bit Windows Operating System` then what are the issues I could face ? Is there any example ?

Comment: int is an alias for Int32, 
long is an alias for Int64

Answer (score 80):

**int**

It is a primitive data type defined in C#.

It is mapped to Int32 of FCL type.

It is a value type and represent System.Int32 struct.

It is signed and takes 32 bits.

It has minimum -2147483648 and maximum +2147483647 value.

**Int16**

It is a FCL type.

In C#, *short* is mapped to Int16.

It is a value type and represent System.Int16 struct.

It is signed and takes 16 bits.

It has minimum -32768 and maximum +32767 value.

**Int32**

It is a FCL type.

In C#, *int* is mapped to Int32.

It is a value type and represent System.Int32 struct.

It is signed and takes 32 bits.

It has minimum -2147483648 and maximum +2147483647 value.

**Int64**

It is a FCL type.

In C#, *long* is mapped to Int64.

It is a value type and represent System.Int64 struct.

It is signed and takes 64 bits.

It has minimum –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and maximum 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 value.

Comment: Just to add that `Int64` data type can be represented using `L` or `l` suffix while `Int16` or `Int32` have not suffix in C#.

Answer (score 17):

According to Jeffrey Richter(one of the contributors of .NET framework development)'s book 'CLR via C#':

int is a primitive type allowed by the C# compiler, whereas Int32 is the Framework Class Library type (available across languages that abide by CLS). In fact, int translates to Int32 during compilation.

Also,

> In C#, long maps to System.Int64, but in a different programming
>   language, long could map to Int16 or Int32. In fact, C++/CLI does
>   treat long as Int32.
>
> In fact, most (.NET) languages won't even treat long as a keyword and won't
>   compile code that uses it.

I have seen this author, and many standard literature on .NET preferring FCL types(i.e., Int32) to the language-specific primitive types(i.e., int), mainly on such interoperability  concerns.

Answer (score 14):

They tell what size can be stored in a integer variable. To remember the size you can think in terms of :-) 2 beers (2 bytes), 4 beers (4 bytes) or 8 beers (8 bytes).

- **Int16** :- 2 beers/bytes = 16 bit = 2^16 = 65536 = 65536/2 = -32768 to  32767
- **Int32** :- 4 beers/bytes = 32 bit = 2^32 = 4294967296 = 4294967296/2 = -2147483648  to  2147483647
- **Int64** :- 8 beers/bytes = 64 bit = 2^64  = 18446744073709551616 = 18446744073709551616/2 = -9223372036854775808 to  9223372036854775807

> In short you can not store more than 32767 value in int16 , more than
> 2147483647 value in int32 and more than 9223372036854775807 value in
> int64.

To understand above calculation you can check out this video [int16 vs int32 vs int64](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEcz_a_4N4o)

[image: int16vsint32vsint64]

Answer (score 8):

1. `int` and `int32` are one and the same (32-bit integer)
2. `int16` is short int (2 bytes or 16-bits)
3. `int64` is the long datatype (8 bytes or 64-bits)

Comment: int is not guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Comment: @mjs, this is simply not true. In C#, `int` is an alias for `Int32` and thus is always guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Comment: Actually what mjs says is correct, INT means integer based on the system x86 or x64, so if your system is x64, int will be Int64, therefore is not guaranteed to be 32.. If you put int32 in a x64 will always be int32.

Comment: No, what David Arno says is correct.  The C# language specifically defines 'int' to mean a 32-bit integer (Int32).  Other languages (C/C++, etc.) may not specify that, but this question is tagged 'C#'.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman Correct, here's Microsoft's page on C#s integral numeric types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: This isn't quite true for C#, a tag I missed when I answered this question - if there is a more C# specific answer, please vote for that instead!

---

They all represent integer numbers of varying sizes.

However, there's a very very tiny difference.

int16, int32 and int64 all have a *fixed* size.

The size of an int depends on the architecture you are compiling for - the C spec only defines an int as larger or equal to a short though in practice it's the width of the processor you're targeting, which is *probably* 32bit but you should know that it might not be.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this is the only one which is actually correct

Comment: No, this isn't true for C#. A C# int is always 32 bits in size. For C, yes you had to deal with this complication and you often see macros in C code to deal with variable int sizes. See http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf page 18.

Comment: @Ananke Ahh, missed the C# tag. Wish I could revert some votes on the answers.....

Answer (score 8):

A very important note on the 16, 32 and 64 types:

if you run this query...
Array.IndexOf(new Int16[]{1,2,3}, 1)

you are suppose to get zero(0) because you are asking... is 1 within the array of 1, 2 or 3.
if you get -1 as answer, it means 1 is not within the array of 1, 2 or 3.

Well check out what I found:
All the following should give you 0 and not -1
(I've tested this in all framework versions 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0)

C#:

```
Array.IndexOf(new Int16[]{1,2,3}, 1) = -1 (not correct)
Array.IndexOf(new Int32[]{1,2,3}, 1) = 0 (correct)
Array.IndexOf(new Int64[]{1,2,3}, 1) = 0 (correct)
```

VB.NET:

```
Array.IndexOf(new Int16(){1,2,3}, 1) = -1 (not correct)
Array.IndexOf(new Int32(){1,2,3}, 1) = 0 (correct)
Array.IndexOf(new Int64(){1,2,3}, 1) = -1 (not correct)
```

So my point is, for Array.IndexOf comparisons, only trust Int32!

Comment: To clarify why the first example works that way: the first literal 1, the 2, and the 3 are implicitly cast to `short` to fit them in the array, while the second literal 1 is left as an ordinary `int`.  `(int)1` is not considered equal to `(short)1`, `(short)2`, `(short)3`, thus the result is -1.

Comment: There'd be a similar adjustment available to the C# versions, but FYI a simple type specifier fixes this issue: `Array.IndexOf(new Int16(){1,2,3}, 1S)` 
`Array.IndexOf(new Int32(){1,2,3}, 1I)` 
`Array.IndexOf(new Int64(){1,2,3}, 1L)` all work as expected.

Comment: And the ones that don't work have used the `Object[],Object` overload. C# is implicitly raising the `int` to a `long` when needed (and also raises a `short` to an `int` or `long`), but will not implicitly cast down, using the `object` overload instead. With `Option Strict On` or `Off` VB will only use the typed overload when provided the uniform types, otherwise it uses the `object` overload.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. The code is comparing values of different types. The conclusion `for Array.IndexOf comparisons, only trust Int32!` is wrong. If you cast the final `1` argument to the corresponding Array type, it works as expected.

Comment: This is a very interesting and unexpected behaviour (since int to long works but short to int doesn't) hence the upvote!

Comment: @DonCheadle Yeah, maybe. But e.g. in Java the value within the array would be automatically be interpreted as `int` (or long if that's given) so this is certainly a little unexpected.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing. The sole difference between the types *is* their size (and, hence, the range of values they can represent).

Answer (score 5):

They both are indeed synonymous, However i found the small difference between them,

1)You cannot use `Int32` while creating`enum`

```
enum Test : Int32
{ XXX = 1   // gives you compilation error
}

enum Test : int
{ XXX = 1   // Works fine
}
```

2) `Int32` comes under System declaration. if you remove `using.System` you will get compilation error but not in case for `int`

Answer (score 0):

The answers by the above people are about right. int, int16, int32... differs based on their data holding capacity. But here is why the compilers have to deal with these - it is to solve the potential Year 2038 problem. Check out the link to learn more about it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the reason a compiler has to deal with different int-sized is not about the year 2038 problem. A compiler just compiles as given. And the solution to the Year 2038 is to use a larger int size indeed, but neither got the 64-bit integer invented because that that, nor does it solve the problem on 32-bit hardware.

Comment: Yes, solution to the problem is using a larger int size. The compiler will never allow storing a large date which dosen't fit in the specified int16 or int32 type. We developers will also be clear that a int32 can only store -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If we need to store a future timestamp we have use unsigned int32

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, there might be some difference in how they handle nan values as well

Example with my pandas my dataframe:

`result['HPosition'].astype('int')`  - returns IntCastingNaNError

`result['HPosition'].astype('Int64')` - runs fine

Answer (score -11):

Int=Int32   --> Original long type

Int16       --> Original int

Int64       --> New data type become available after 64 bit systems

"int" is only available for backward compatibility. We should be really using new int types to make our programs more precise.

---------------

**One more thing** I noticed along the way is there is no class named `Int` similar to Int16, Int32 and Int64. All the helpful functions like `TryParse` for integer come from `Int32.TryParse`.