# which method it is called on 3.ToString();

Tags: c#

Which method it is called on 3.ToString()?

1. System.Int16.ToString()
2. System.Int32.ToString()
3. System.Int64.ToString()

Comment: You could answer this yourself by checking what `3.GetType()` returns

Comment: have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696660/what-is-the-difference-between-int-int16-int32-int64

Comment: To whomever is closing this as "not constructive" and "not a real question" -- I think you all need to reassess what those close reasons are for.  The only reasonable ones might be "too localized" (common knowledge) or because it's a dup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All integer literals in C# default to `int` (`Int32`) unless they are too big for `int`, in which case they become a larger data type that fits, like `long`(`Int64`).

So in this case, `Int32.ToString()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but reading your solution made me realize that first it tries Int32 than UInt32, than Int64 and then UInt64.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Int32.ToString()` as literal integers are Int32 type

Comment: This is true is this particular case, but note that if the literal exceeds the capacity of an `int`, it will be promoted to a `long`.