# Changing the type of values in arrays resulting from sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm doing [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/support-vector-machine-intro-machine-learning-tutorial/) on machine learning in which the following code is used:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.csv')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace = True)
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace = True)
X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1))
y = np.array(df['class'])

X_train, X_test, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Here is a sample from the csv file:

```
id,clump_thickness,unif_cell_size,unif_cell_shape, marg_adhesion,
single_epith_cell_size,bare_nuclei,bland_chrom,norm_nucleoli, mitoses,class
    1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
    1002945,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
    1015425,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
    1016277,6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1,2
    1017023,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1,2
    1017122,8,10,10,8,7,10,9,7,1,4
    1018099,1,1,1,1,2,10,3,1,1,2
    1018561,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
    1033078,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,2
    1033078,4,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
    1035283,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
    1036172,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
    1041801,5,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,1,4
    1043999,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2
    1044572,8,7,5,10,7,9,5,5,4,4
    1047630,7,4,6,4,6,1,4,3,1,4
    1048672,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
    1049815,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
    1050670,10,7,7,6,4,10,4,1,2,4
    1050718,6,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
    1054590,7,3,2,10,5,10,5,4,4,4
    1054593,10,5,5,3,6,7,7,10,1,4
    1056784,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
    1057013,8,4,5,1,2,?,7,3,1,4
    1059552,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
    1065726,5,2,3,4,2,7,3,6,1,4
    1066373,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
```

When looking at the results from `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` I found out something weird (at least to me). If I run

```
    print(type(y_test[0]))
    print()
    print(type(X_train[:,1][0]))
```

I get the following output:

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'int'>
```

Somehow the values in `X_train` are of the type `int` and the values in `y_test` are of the type `numpy.int64`. I don't know why `train_test_split` does this - I don't think it has to do with the data that is being split up - and the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) doesn't seem to mention it either.

Since I want the values in `y_test` to be regular integers as well, I tried changing the type of `y_test` with `astype()`. Unfortunately, the following code

```
y_test = y_test.astype(int)
print(type(y_test[0]))
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

**Question:** Why does `train_test_split` return arrays containing values with different kinds of datatypes? Why am I not able to convert the values in `y_test` to integers?

**Edit:** The difference in type is caused by the data. If I run

```
 print(type(X[:,1][0]))
 print(type(y[0]))
```

I get

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I still would like to know why astype doesn't work though!:)

Comment: There's not much of a difference here, other than just a couple of bytes. From my personal experience, numpy prefers to store results in `int64` (so this is for `y_test`), while normal arrays simply store as `int`. Can refer to the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696660/what-is-the-difference-between-int-int16-int32-and-int64

Comment: @Shiv_90 Thank you for your reply! There are some practical differences though. For example, inserting the data into a datatable column with type 'numeric' works with `int` but not with `numpy.int64`

Comment: I see. And there could be many reasons behind this exclusivity; although this is not my sure answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To convert numpy values to python types, there's [numpy.ndarray.item](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html)

```
y_test_int = [v.item() for v in y_test]
print(type(y_test_int[0]))
#<class 'int'>
```