# What the difference between int32 and int64

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I changed the type of AGHIGH, AGELOW from float to integer but I found the output is int32 not int64 by using that code

```
df[['AGEHIGH', 'AGELOW']] = df[['AGEHIGH', 'AGELOW']].astype(int)
```

```
1   SCHNAME     13902 non-null  object
2   LOCALITY    13902 non-null  object
3   TOWN        13902 non-null  object
4   SCHSTATUS   13902 non-null  object
5   MINORGROUP  13902 non-null  object
6   AGELOW      13902 non-null  int32 
7   AGEHIGH     13902 non-null  int32 
8   GENDER      13902 non-null  object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered very well over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696660/what-is-the-difference-between-int-int16-int32-and-int64).

The key difference is in terms of storage capacity. An integer is held in bits (1s and 0s). Very simply a 64-bit integer can store a much larger/smaller number by virtue of having more bits.

> Type      Capacity
>
> Int16 -- (-32,768 to +32,767)
>
> Int32 -- (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647)
>
> Int64 -- (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Comment: So you want the output to be int64 and not int32 (the default)?

Comment: Try amending astype(int) to astype(int64)

Comment: name 'int64' is not defined

Comment: this is the output

Comment: You are using numpy with pandas dataframes is that right?

Try the below (assuming you have defined numpy as np)
df[['AGEHIGH', 'AGELOW']] = df[['AGEHIGH', 'AGELOW']].astype(np.int64)