# When to use short?

Tags: c#, short

Say I'm looping through like 20/30 objects or in any other case where I'm dealing with smaller numbers, is it a good practice to use short instead of int?

I mean why isn't this common:

```
for(short i=0; i<x; i++)
    Method(array[i]);
```

Is it because the performance gain is too low?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [.NET Integer vs Int16?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129023/net-integer-vs-int16)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Integer vs Int16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129023/net-integer-vs-int16)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"is it a good practice to use short instead of int?"

First of all, this is a micro optimization that will not achieve the expected results: increase speed or efficiency.

Second: No, not really, the CLR internally still uses 32 bit integers (Int32) to perform the iteration. Basically it converts short to Int32 for computation purposes during JIT compilation.

Third: Array indexes are Int32, and the iterating short variable is automatically converted to int32 when used as an array indexer.

If we take the next code:

```
    var array = new object[32];
    var x = array.Length;
    for (short i = 0; i < x; i++)
        Method(array[i]);
```

And disassemble it, you can clearly see at  `00000089  inc         eax` that at machine level an 32 bit register was used for the iterating variable (eax), which is next truncated to 16 bit `0000008a  movsx       eax,ax`  so there are no benefits from using a short oppossed to using an int32, actually there might be a slight performance loss due to extra instructions that need to be executed.

```
00000042  nop 
            var array = new object[32];
00000043  mov         ecx,64B41812h 
00000048  mov         edx,20h 
0000004d  call        FFBC01A4 
00000052  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax 
00000055  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-50h] 
00000058  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax 
            var x = array.Length;
0000005b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000005e  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+4] 
00000061  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax 
            for (short i = 0; i < x; i++)
00000064  xor         edx,edx 
00000066  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],edx 
00000069  nop 
0000006a  jmp         00000090 
                Method(array[i]);
0000006c  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
0000006f  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000072  cmp         eax,dword ptr [edx+4] 
00000075  jb          0000007C 
00000077  call        657A28F6 
0000007c  mov         ecx,dword ptr [edx+eax*4+0Ch] 
00000080  call        FFD9A708 
00000085  nop 
            for (short i = 0; i < x; i++)
00000086  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
00000089  inc         eax 
0000008a  movsx       eax,ax 
0000008d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax 
00000090  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
00000093  cmp         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h] 
00000096  setl        al 
00000099  movzx       eax,al 
0000009c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax 
0000009f  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],0 
000000a3  jne         0000006C
```

Comment: So when is it beneficial to use a short or a byte over an int?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the performance difference is negligible. However, a short uses 16 bits instead of 32 for an int, so it's conceivable that you may want to use a short if you're processing enough small numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using numbers that matches the word size of the processor is relatively faster than unmatching numbers. On the other hand, short uses less memory space than int.
If you have a limited memory space, using short may be the alternative; but personally I have never encountered such a thing when writing c# applications.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` uses 32 bits of memory, a `short` uses 16 bits and a `byte` uses 8 bits. If you're only looping through 20/30 objects and you're concerned about memory usage, use `byte` instead.

Catering for memory usage to this level is rarely required with today's machines, though you could argue that using `int` everywhere is just lazy. Personally, I try to always use the relevant type that uses the least memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(v=vs.100).aspx